# Flutter model how to get information from an object nested in an array?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

For example, JSON looks like this:

```
{
 "id": 12151,
 "cadastres":[
  {
   "general_info": {
    "area": 1515,
    "datev": "20.12.20"
    }
  },
  {
   "general_info": {
    "area": 1151,
    "datev": "10.12.10"
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to get each of these values.
I created a model:

```
class Cadastre {
  final int id;
  final double area;
  final String creationDate;

  Cadastre(
      {required this.id,
      required this.area,
      required this.creationDate});

  factory Cadastre.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Cadastre(
        id: map['id'],
        area: map['area'],
        creationDate: map['datev'],);
  }
}
```

In this way, I would get only the ID correctly, how can I get data for the model from an object nested in an array?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON returns an id and a list of cadastre objects. If you want to have a reference of the id in each model, I will suggest this implementation:

```
class Cadastre {
  final int id;
  final double area;
  final String creationDate;

  Cadastre({
    required this.id,
    required this.area,
    required this.creationDate,
  });

  /*
  You will use it like this:

  final cadastres = Cadastre.fromJsonList(json['id'], json['cadastres']);
  */
  static List<Cadastre> fromJsonList(int id, List<Map<String, dynamic>> list) {
    return list.map((map) {
      map.putIfAbsent("id", () => id);

      return Cadastre.fromJson(map);
    }).toList();
  }

  factory Cadastre.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Cadastre(
      id: map["id"],
      area: map['area'],
      creationDate: map['datev'],
    );
  }
}
```